Couldn't create a new flutter project on vscode
I'm on vscode and trying to start a flutter project ( note: when i was installing flutter and dart it did not give me an option to locate SDK) and now when i click on "Flutter:new project" it doesn't open the bin of flutter file with the new projectenter image description here
I've watched couple of youtube videos and they all had the chance to locate sdk and when they start the new flutter project all the components of bin folder in the flutter is opened sutomatically as shown in the pictureenter image description here

Are you trying to do this with Windows or Mac? Also have you added it to path?

In command prompt /yourpath: Flutter create projectName this command is to create flutter project, You can view in VS code. here
I hope this might help you,

First of all , We need to check for whether Flutter SDK is installed properly or not by using flutter doctor if not then
1) Make sure that the environment variables are set correctly, if it a windows then
Go to “Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > Change my
environment variables”
Under “User variables” check if there is an entry called “Path”:
If the entry does exist, append the full path to flutter\bin using ; as a
separator from existing values.
If the entry does not exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full
path to flutter\bin as its value.
2) Reboot your computer
and after that try running flutter doctor from terminal again
